# Print number of lines matching conditions in files generated by count

Tags: linux, bash, awk, while-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to print, using purely awk, lines who satisfied the count number provided by a *while count* loop in bash. Here's some lines of the input.

```
NODE_1_posplwpl
NODE_1_owkokwo
NODE_1_kslkow
NODE_2_fbjfh
NODE_2_lsmlsm
NODE_3_Loskos
NODE_3_pospls
```

What i want to do is to print lines who match, in their second field, the count number provided by the *while count* loop, into a file named file_$count_test.
So a file called "file_1_test" will contain lines with "NODE_1.." , "file_2_test" will contain lines with "NODE_2.." ; like that with all the lines of the file.
Here's my code.

```
#! /bin/bash

while read CNAME
do
    let count=$count+1
    grep "^${CNAME}_" > file_${count}_test
    awk -v X=$count '{ FS="_" } { if ($2 == X) print $0 }' > file_${count}_test
done <$1
exit 1
```

This code creates only the file_1_test, which is empty. So the awk condition seems to work bad.

Comment: Please POST sample input in your post in CODE TAGS, providing links for sample inputs and outputs are NOT recommended.

Comment: Provided only some lines of the input.

Comment: No need of using `while` loop here, if you could tell us what you are trying to do then we could do it in single `awk` itself. please add that logic too in your post now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to split your input into separate files named based on the number between the underscores. That'd just be:

```
awk -F'_' '{print > ("file_" $2 "_test")}' file
```

You may need to change it to:

```
awk -F'_' '$2!=prev{close(out); out="file_" $2 "_test"} {print > out; prev=$2}' file
```

if you're generating a lot of output files and not using GNU awk as that could lead to a "too many open files" error.

wrt your comments below, look:

```
$ cat file
NODE_1_posplwpl
NODE_1_owkokwo
NODE_1_kslkow
NODE_2_fbjfh
NODE_2_lsmlsm
NODE_3_Loskos
NODE_3_pospls

$ awk -F'_' '{print $0 " > " ("file_" $2 "_test")}' file
NODE_1_posplwpl > file_1_test
NODE_1_owkokwo > file_1_test
NODE_1_kslkow > file_1_test
NODE_2_fbjfh > file_2_test
NODE_2_lsmlsm > file_2_test
NODE_3_Loskos > file_3_test
NODE_3_pospls > file_3_test
```

Just change `$0 " > "` to `>` like in the first script to have the output go to the separate files instead of just showing you that that would happen like this last script does.

Comment: These files need to contain every line matching the number between underscores.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was assuming. Did you try it? If it didn't do what you want then edit your question to clarify what it is you want and provide the expected output. Don't just describe the expected output - SHOW the expected output.

Comment: The provided command prints into a single file all the content of the input file.

Comment: No it does not. Unless your input doesn't really look like the input you showed us of course.

Comment: Do I need to integrate it into the while loop? Using it alone gives a single output file.

Comment: No. There is no while loop. That is the whole command to do what I THINK it is you're trying to do. I added another command to demonstrate what the script does. Please do try it.

Comment: Works, amazing how things could be easy just using awk. I tried before just the second command, there's why I've said that actually doesn't do what I asked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The 2nd command was testing $1 when it should have been $2, fixed now.